# Finding an AWS account from access key

Tags: amazon-web-services

Strange situation - I inherited a piece of software.  This software has AWS access through an Access Key and Secret, and I have both of those.  However, the person who handed this to me doesn't know the actual *account* that was used to create this.  Is there some way to figure out an account name from an access key/secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the key **and** the secret, configure the CLI with them and use [`aws iam get-user`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html).

With no arguments, this command defaults to querying for the user making the request.  The response will include an ARN, containing the AWS account number.

You should get similar results with another alternative, [`aws sts get-caller-identity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html).

Comment: This worked, but, unfortunately, this only gets me the UserID, which isn't enough to login with.  However, I was able to contact AWS support with it and have them send an email to the account owner, and we are looking through email accounts to find who owns it (they would not give me the email address, either).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The response should have given you an ARN with the account number.